# Creating an internal nudge following completion of a task in Marketing cloud

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

Wishing to create a "nudge" for a Marketing cloud user following the completion of a task in Campaign journey.

E.g. Customer receives SMS - MC triggers and internal nudge to Campaign Exec to complete external task .

Can this be done within Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible through the activities provided but remember You can create a custom integration but that will require coding skills as need to be done on the code layer from the Journey Builder tool.

As is recommended [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297369/using-ssjs-in-journey-builder), you could call a SSJS script using another activity that at the time will trigger the automation that will do.